# jsp отобразить результат выполнения

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, классы, jsp

Есть java class который выполняется и возвращает результат

Код:

```
package Test;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.asteriskjava.manager.ManagerConnection;
import org.asteriskjava.manager.ManagerConnectionFactory;
import org.asteriskjava.manager.action.CommandAction;
import org.asteriskjava.manager.response.CommandResponse;



public class Manager
{
    private ManagerConnection c;

    public Manager() throws Exception
    {
        ManagerConnectionFactory factory = new ManagerConnectionFactory(
                "tttt", "admin", "ttt");
        c =  factory.createManagerConnection();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        c.login();

        CommandAction action;
        CommandResponse response;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


        action = new CommandAction();
        action.setCommand(" sip show peers");
        response = (CommandResponse) c.sendAction(action);

        list = response.getResult();
        for (String s : list) {
            if (s.contains("VOIP")) {
            out.print(s);

            }
        }

        c.logoff();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new Manager().run();


    }
}
```

Результат выполнения:

```
TEST         172.28.1.1                                  a             5060     OK (4 ms)                                    tes          172.28.1.1                                  a             5060     OK (2 ms)                                      at Test.Manager.main(Manager.java:50)
Java Result: 1
СБОРКА УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНА (общее время: 5 секунды)
```

jsp код

```
<%@page import="Test.Manager" %>
<%
    Manager o = new Manager();
    o.run();
    out.print(o);
%>
```

При вызове JSP в браузере я вижу что данный код выполнился (Видно что он ломанулся на сервер и получил данные) но на странице в браузера отображается "Test.Manager@1237c263" Как исправить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет, дело в том, что когда ты делаешь `out.print(o)`, java ищет метод `toString()` у класса `Manager`, но не находит, поэтому используется метод `toString()` у класса, являющегося родителем класса `Manager` (а это класс `Object`). Чтобы код заработал в таком виде, нужно реализовать метод `toString()` для твоего класса `Manager`. Сделать это можно, например, следующим образом:

```
public class Manager
{
    // тут весь предыдущий код, но его придется поменять

    public String toString()
    {
        // то, что нужно вывести на страницу
    }
}
```

Для этого нужно будет немного переписать твой класс. Второй способ мне кажется более простым, сделать можно так:

```
public class Manager
{
    private ManagerConnection c;

    public Manager() throws Exception
    {
        ManagerConnectionFactory factory = new ManagerConnectionFactory(
                "tttt", "admin", "ttt");
        c = factory.createManagerConnection();
    }

    public String run() throws Exception
    {
        c.login();

        CommandAction action;
        CommandResponse response;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        action = new CommandAction();
        action.setCommand(" sip show peers");
        response = (CommandResponse) c.sendAction(action);

        list = response.getResult();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : list) {
            if (s.contains("VOIP")) {
                stringBuilder.append(s);
            }
        }

        c.logoff();

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new Manager().run();
    }
}
```

То есть я немного видоизменил метод `run()`, теперь этот метод будет возвращать строку. Тогда саму jsp нужно написать так:

```
<%@page import="Test.Manager" %>
<%
    Manager o = new Manager();
    out.print(o.run());
%>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш пример помог. Подскажите, а каким образом исходя из Вашего примера строку можно разбить на массив ?

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать? Отфильтровать из `list` те значения, которые содержат "VOIP"? Если так, то тогда не нужно было их в одну строку соединять. Предлагаю, например, завести новую коллекцию `List<String> voipList` и в цикле делать `voipList.add(s)` вместо текущего `stringBuilder.append(s)`. И пусть тогда метод `run()` возвращает List<String> вместо String.